# Android: Get all the frames of a video (any video file)

Tags: android, video, bitmap, frames

Good day mates,

I'm working on a simple application that is connected in editing videos.

What i need is to get all the frames of a video (as what i know, frames can be treated as bitmaps)

after getting them all, I need to edit the frames(bitmaps)
then display it in an imageview (though what I'll do is, loop all the images like they are videos.

I tried to use the

```
mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(0);
```

but the problem is, the frames the capture in a given time is not correct.

sample code:

```
bm[1] = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(0);
bm[2] = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(50000);
bm[3] = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(100000);
bm[4] = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(150000);
bm[5] = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(200000);
```

then loop the bitmap in an imageview.

I've heard about the ffmpeg and tried to study about it.

The problem is, I;m using windows and not ubuntu or linux.

I'm really having hard time as of now.

Please help me or just direct me in a correct path.

THANKS A LOT :)

Answer (score 1):

Take care that [MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long%29) method uses parameter which represents time offset value in microseconds (1/1000000th part of a second) and not in milliseconds (1/1000th part).

That might solve at least the problems you've got with capturing frames by using [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).

Anyway, it could be interesting for you to check for some alternatives like [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) which represents wrapper for OpenCV, FFmpeg and some other popular image and video processing libraries. JavaCV is supported for Windows, Linux, Mac OS and Android.

JavaCV lacks better documentation for sure but there are some examples on their home page which could be good starting point. 
More advanced examples could be found at [Cookbook Examples](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples) written in Scala. With some basic understanding of that language it could be valuable resource even for pure Java developers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever), which uses FFmpeg as it's backend:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
bm[1] = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(0);
bm[2] = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(50000);
bm[3] = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(100000);
bm[4] = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(150000);
bm[5] = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(200000);
fmmr.release();
```